# PrintLn header for C++

Tags: c++

I've always wondered what's the most elegant way of implementing PrintLn in C++. I have not yet come with perfect conclusion. This is my shot.

Shortcut for std::cout, std::cerr and std::clog "print line" version. So you can type 
`CoutLn << "Hello world!";` instead of `std::cout << "Hello world!" << '\n';`

**CoutLn**, **CerrLn**, **ClogLn** are implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <mutex>

/* Template magic: determine if our type is printable. */
template<typename S, typename T, typename = void>
struct is_to_stream_writable : std::false_type {};
template<typename S, typename T>
struct is_to_stream_writable<S, T, std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<S&>()<<std::declval<T>())>> : std::true_type {};

/* Since std::cout, std::cerr etc. are all different instances of the same type, 
 * let's define dummy classes for detecting different instances. */
class Cout{};
class Cerr{};
class Clog{};

template<class Stream = Cout>
class PrintLn {
  private:
    static std::ostream* stream;
    static std::mutex m;
  public:
    PrintLn() {
      if constexpr (std::is_same<Stream, Cout>::value) stream = &std::cout;
      else if constexpr (std::is_same<Stream, Cerr>::value) stream = &std::cerr;
      else if constexpr (std::is_same<Stream, Clog>::value) stream = &std::clog;
    }
    template<class T>
    PrintLn& operator<<(const T& msg) {
      static_assert(is_to_stream_writable<std::ostream, T>::value, "your type is not printable");
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(PrintLn<Stream>::m);
      *stream << msg;
      return *this;
    }
    ~PrintLn() {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(PrintLn<Stream>::m);
      *stream << '\n';
    }
};

/* Declare static variables. */
template<class Stream>
typename::std::mutex PrintLn<Stream>::m;

template<class Stream>
typename::std::ostream* PrintLn<Stream>::stream;

using CoutLn = PrintLn<Cout>;
using CerrLn = PrintLn<Cerr>;
using ClogLn = PrintLn<Clog>;

/* Shorter syntax, for example: `CerrLn{} << "error";` -> `CerrLn << "error";`. */
#define CoutLn CoutLn{}
#define CerrLn CerrLn{}
#define ClogLn ClogLn{}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [C++20 `osyncstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream)?  It seems to have a better interface.

## Multithreading

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(PrintLn<Stream>::m);
```

This line is useless, because temporary objects are destroyed at the end of the full-expression.  (Does this even have a temporary in C++17?)  You need a named variable instead.  Also make use of class template argument deduction:

```
std::lock_guard lock{m};
```

Also,

## Streams

Your approach is unnecessarily restricted because only three hardcoded streams `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, and `std::clog` are supported.  And I think `{}` is OK and these don't really help a lot:

```
#define CoutLn CoutLn{}
#define CerrLn CerrLn{}
#define ClogLn ClogLn{}
```

Make the function object have regular semantics instead.  You may use a hash map internally to store the mutexes, as `syncbuf` does.

Also SFINAE on `operator<<`.

---

Here's the same thing implemented with `osyncstream`:

```
template <
    class CharT,
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<CharT>
> class PrintLn : public std::basic_osyncstream<CharT, Traits, Allocator> {
    using Base = std::basic_osyncstream<CharT, Traits, Allocator>;
public:
    using Base::Base;

    PrintLn(PrintLn&&) = default;
    PrintLn& operator=(PrintLn&&) = default;
    ~PrintLn()
    {
        if (this->get_wrapped()) {
            *static_cast<Base*>(this) << '\n';
        }
    }
};

inline auto cout_ln()
{
    return PrintLn{std::cout};
}
inline auto cerr_ln()
{
    return PrintLn{std::cerr};
}
inline auto clog_ln()
{
    return PrintLn{std::clog};
}
```

But anyway, why would you wanna do this when you can simply print a `\n`?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend C++20 features until most major compilers (G++, Clang++, MSVC++) support them. Even then, it might not hurt to wait a couple of years so those compilers that support them get to enough platforms.